# Additional options to protect from bad USB devices in ubuntu

Tags: attack-prevention, usb-drive, usb

In addiition to the solution options in the other threads

[How to prevent BadUSB attacks on Linux desktop?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64524/how-to-prevent-badusb-attacks-on-linux-desktop)
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/77072/protecting-against-bad-usb-in-ubuntu

i wanted to ask if it is possible in ubuntu somehow to monitor all adapters HID devices USB devices and soon and so forth (i guess maybe using the system protocoll it could be achieved?)

I personally only know the lsusb command that is quite useful but i guess there is for sure a better way to watch out for possible fake devices being added after inserting a possibly infected usb device?

Comment: USB has no authentication. Any device can pretend to be any other device. Not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: There are ways to monitor. However, they offer no protection against badUSB, as the device could immediately use its control over the PC to hide everything suspicious.

Comment: The problem is this: there's no way to verify data sent from device. So, if the device says "my ID is `045e:00db`," how does the computer know that it's not actually `abad:d00d`? (It doesn't.)